# I can not do any modify after Octopress installed

Tags: github

I have seted up Octopress with the Octopress Documentation.
I installed Octopress on GitHub. And My OS is Ubuntu.
There is something I meet:

1. When I  modified `_config.yml` , and `git push origin source`. But the Web does not change.
2. When I added CNAME at octopress_path/source, and `git push origin source`. But I found there  no CNAME on `master branch`, And CNAME is at `source branch'.
3. When I added a article, and generate it. After I `git push origin source`, The GitHub has the article, but the Web still is nothing.

I am new to octopress, and I Google it, but I don't konw why.
How can I solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must have forgot run:

```
$ rake deploy
```

It'll help you to generate the `master` branch (which is the site to show), and it'll be pushed to github automatically. The `source` is just the source code for your site, not for showing.

**Note**: every time you modified (or added) a post, and ready to deploy, you need to run `rake deploy`. And `rake preview` is for testing locally. See official doc by yourself. :)

---

If it is the first time, you need to run

```
$ rake setup_github_pages
```

to setup github pages for you.

Then every time you add a post, run

```
$ rake generate
$ rake deploy
```

Comment: Thanks. I try to run `rake deploy`, but the web still is nothing. And I can preview on http://localhost:4000. The localhost shows what I added and modified.

Comment: @CloverStd check your github repo, does there have a `master` branch?

Comment: Yes, There have a `master` branch.  And the `_deploy` folder is belong to `master`.

Comment: @CloverStd what is your github account? Let me have a look :)

Answer (score 0):

i have just encountered the same error like yours,and fortunately i find the solution!

i wanna ask you a question :when you executed "rake generate",did you see the error from the output of the command? the error i met is just like this :

chienlung@chienlung:~/octopress$ rake generate

Generating Site with Jekyll
unchanged sass/screen.scss
/home/chienlung/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/maruku-0.6.0/lib/maruku/input/parse_doc.rb:22:in `<top (required)>': iconv will be deprecated in the future, use String#encode instead.
/home/chienlung/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:203:in`parse': (/home/chienlung/octopress/_config.yml): **could not find expected ':' while scanning a simple key at line 10 column 1** (Psych::SyntaxError)

then i immediately checked my _config.yml file, it likes this :

。。some lines here。。。。

url: http://Chienlung.github.com

title: 陆彦帑的博客

subtitle: 宗介波妞手拉手，宗介永远爱波妞。

author: 陆彦帑

simple_search:

description:愿我如星君如月，夜夜流光相皎洁。

the line ten is : **description:愿我如星君如月，夜夜流光相皎洁。**

。。。。other lines from here。。。。。

the error from the "space" following by the word "description".

i modified the space to be like other line(like "url: http://Chienlung.github.com"),then i excuted "rake generate" and "rake deploy",it works!!!!

im a newbie ,i guess the reason for this error is Encoding。

Hope to help you.

祝你好运！